# Cant exec "usleep" in Perl language

Tags: perl, file, usleep

Im learning Perl and I have one problem. I designed an easy program, but when I run it this error appears:

```
Can not exec "usleep": The file or directory does not exist at line 22 example.pl.

Can not exec "usleep": The file or directory does not exist at line 65 example.pl.
```

How can solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code you are asking a question about.

Comment: Yeah, that would help

Answer (score 8):

Instead of executing an external program, you may want to look into the [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) module. This can do what you want in a more straightforward manner.

```
use Time::HiRes 'usleep';

usleep($microseconds);
```

Comment: Another alternative to Time::HiRes is using the `select` function. For example, to effect a sleep of 250 milliseconds: `select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);` However, Time::HiRes is a core mod, and probably the perferred method.